# Вставить данные в бд по отдельности

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет, не знаю как вставить данные в бд через phpmyadmin по отдельности, всего 4 столбца: id, realname, password, ip. Я создал таблицу и вставил в неё только name и добавил колонку id, однако при попытке вставить другие части базы данных, они переносятся вниз, т.е. не вставляются в пустое место, где нет значений в строке.
Как можно это обыграть и вставить рядом realname, password и ip? Вроде как можно через UPDATE и PHP, но не знаю как, подскажите пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from auth;
insert into auth (realname, password, ip) values ('foo', 'pass', '127.0.0.1'), ...
```